# What are compatibile motors with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian

What are compatibile motors with Raspberry Pi ? If I'm building humanodoid robot what is the best choose ? Do you think that I should use [this board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11561) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no motor that you will be able to connect directly to the Raspberry Pi, so the best type would be determined by the robot's needs.

That said, given the limited GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi I would recommend getting a motor driver that can control many motors with minimal connections to the Raspberry Pi.

For example [this 16 channel I2C Servo Driver](http://www.adafruit.com/products/815).  There is a [tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi) about using that board with the Raspberry Pi to control 16 servos.

The sparkfun board seems to be designed for wheeled robots so it may not be right for a humanoid robot.